# Insert in many tables with My_Model in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-abstraction

I have a site developed in codeigniter.I have done an insert into my database without validation.
Now I want to  use My_Model (an extended model to validate my fields used by many developer to validate fields in codeigniter downloadd from github) but if in my function I have to make more insert into different tables? How can I done this? Because for example if I have a product I insert its data into the database and now with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID` I take its  id and insert the image with that product_id in the some function like this:

```
        $product = array('name'=>'test');
        $this->db->insert('product',$product);
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
        $row = $query->row_array();
        $product_id = $row['LAST_INSERT_ID()'];
        $img = array(
                 'product_id'=>$product_id,
             'url'=>$url)       
                );
        $this->db->insert('img',$img);
```

Now with My_Model I have this function:

```
   $product = array('name'=>'test');
   $nation_id = $this->insert($product);
   $this->load->model('backend/Img_model');
   $img_model = new Img_Model();
   $img = array(
             'product_id'=>$product_id,
             'url'=>$url
         );
   return $img_model->insert($img);
```

The problem is that: In Nation_Model I have an array of validate to check my field and in Img_Model I have another validate array like this (is only an example):

```
 public $validate = array(
        array( 'field' => 'name', 
               'label' => 'name',
               'rules' => 'required),
     );
```

but when I try to insert: the first insert is ok, the second insert doesn't take the validate array of the Img_Model but take the validate_array of the nation_Model. How can I solve this?

Comment: `return $img->insert($img);` shouldn't that be `return $test->insert($img)`.

Comment: also it would help if you provided the names of the functions in both the model and MY_Model

Comment: you need to provided a more clear explanation. provide method names and your expected logical flow.